# Android how to judge a activity is in foreground and do some logic

Tags: java, android

The Activity is singleTop, and I know that it will invoke onNewIntent if start it again,
but I want do some logic if the Activity is forground. 
android didn't recommand use ActivityManager getRecentTasks

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will help you

```
          ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
          ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
          String currentActivity=taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

          if(currentActivity.equals("SomeActivity"))
          {

            //Do your Task

          }
```

Comment: from android develop say getRunningTasks(int maxNum) was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still retu rn a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive.